# BindingSource Will Not Reflect Updated Data In DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

When I update the list bound to the `BindingSource` it is not reflected in the `DataGridView`.

I am doing the following:

```
private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
private BindingList<object> cameraList = new BindingList<object>();
```

Then after initializing the control:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = cameraList;
dgvCameras.AutoGenerateColumns = false;            
dgvCameras.DataSource = bindingSource;
SetColumDetails(); // This defines the columns and associates the object property names to the columns;
```

Then in the thread that does the work:

```
cameraList = GetCameras();
bindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
```

Updated data is not reflected in the `DataGridView`.

I tried looping over the `bindingSource.ResetItem(i)` but that did not work either.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated... Help!

Comment: Please consider positing a [MCVE], because there may be something wrong in the code which we don't see.

Comment: `object` is not an all purpose type which will match any object type - it wont have any of the properties of whatever `GetCameras()` returns.  Assuming that is something like a `Camera` object, it should be `...new BindingList<Camera>()`

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Thanks. That is helpful to know.